# Power Query , call API using cell value

Tags: powerquery

Hi Im brand new to PowerQuery and trying to use it to interate throught values in a table using CVE value as the varible for an api call and then return the result value(s)

Its a simple table as below:

| CVE | EPSS |
| --- | --- |
| CVE-2023-33228 | Returned by API |

In affect I have a list of CVE numbers I want to check via this api api.first.org/data/v1/epss?cve=**CVE-2022-27225**

The CVE is bold is the changing varible called from the table with result dropped into the EPSS Column.

I can query the API in PowerQuery but struggling to link to changing varible...

Any help greatfull recieved, hopefully this makes sense...

Best
Dean

Comment: you have not provided enough info, but in general set up a function that contains [the API link with the CVE as a variable], then call it multiple times

Comment: Every query name and step name are variables. If you need a loop you can use `Add Custom Column` then use the column in the url like `Web.Contents( [CVE] )` -- Here's a template I wrote that's overkill, but it might help https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerBI/comments/17tynw5/i_made_a_template_for_calling_web_apis_using/